# how to set min height of router outlet in angular 5?

Tags: angular5

in the below code the router-outlet is in between 'app-header' and 'app-footer' components.How can I retrieve the screen height and 'app-header' height? and I want to set deduction of these two heights((screen)-('app-header')) as the  min height of router outlet.is that possible?

**app.components.ts**

```
  <app-header (toggleMenu)="toggleMenu($event)" *ngIf="headerVisible"></app-header>

    <!-- Content -->
      <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
    <!-- Footer -->

      <app-footer (toggleFooterLanguage)="toggleFooterLanguage($event)" *ngIf="footerVisible"></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

> app.component.html

```
<div class="my-router-outlet">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

> app.component.scss

```
.my-router-outlet {
   /* reduce the height of header and footer(170px) as an example*/
   min-height: calc(100vh - 170px); 
}
```